# How can I filter numerical values by entry field in Hugo

Tags: forms, filter, taxonomy, hugo

I'm trying to build a page using Hugo. There I want to add two entry fields for years which shall serve as an upper and lower bound. They should then search my tags and give all tags between the range (practically filter by year). I so far have an entry field and can filter my tags with range, but how can I give the value

This is what I have so far. There is no way I get the input from the entry field into my code

```
<div>
  <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Bitte Jahr eingeben" name="search-input" class="form-control">
</div>
<div id="search-results" class="container"></div>

<section id="menu">
    <ul>
        {{ range $key, $taxonomy := .Site.Taxonomies.tags }}
        {{ if lt $key "input" }}
        <li> {{ $key }} </li>
        
        <ul>
            {{ range $taxonomy.Pages }}
            <li hugo-nav="{{ .RelPermalink}}"><a href="{{ .Permalink}}"> {{ .LinkTitle }} </a> </li>
            {{ end }}
        </ul>
        {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing on very important thing: The Hugo code is executed upon build, while the input is given at the moment of interaction. There is no way that you can get the user input in a Hugo templating variable, simply because it is executed much earlier than the interaction.

To fix this you can let the Hugo code create DOM nodes with custom attributes and let the interaction read them with an onchange event on the input. Then you can show/hide the desired ones by walking over all of them.

The HTML:

```
<select onchange="filterPosts(this.value)">
   <option value="">select year</option>
   <option value="2023">2023</option>
   <option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li data-year="2023">...</li>
  <li data-year="2023">...</li>
  <li data-year="2023">...</li>
  <li data-year="2022">...</li>
  <li data-year="2022">...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The Javascript function:

```
function filterPosts(year) {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-year]');
  els.forEach(function(el) {
    if(year) {
      if (el.dataset.year == year) el.style.display = '';
      else el.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      el.style.display = '';
    }      
  });
}
```

Comment: I was afraid so. It answers my question, but how can I implement it? Can I use JavaScript to implement something like that? That's how my search works.

Comment: I updated the answer with a direction... does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have to think about that because I'm ranging over 500 years and at best I would have been possible to make a two handed slider, but that seems out of the question for now  (I'm not strong in JS). 
You helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For making a search / filtering on a static site using Hugo, you can use [LunrJS](https://lunrjs.com/), which is a Javascript search module.

The free [Hugo Learn theme](https://learn.netlify.app/en/) has a great implementation of this, including an autocomplete. LunrJS reads a index.json file that contains a list of the posts and pages generated by Hugo. You can tweak the template to add the tags you want, so that LunrJS can search amongst them.